# Is it possible to redirect the users to Huawei App Gallery using with Deferred Links?

Tags: android, deep-linking, branch.io, huawei-mobile-services

Since new generation device of Huawei does not support google services, there is only one app market for that devices is App Gallery.
Currently, i am using "Deferred Deep Links" for App store and Play store to route the users who didn't installed the app when link is opened.

Is there any possibility to route non-gms Huawei phone users to App Gallery to download the app?

Comment: Also please note that deferred Deep linking will still work if your users download your application from a custom URL link as well.

Comment: https://www.adjust.com/product-updates/huawei-app-gallery-referrer-api-integration/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

Currently, App Linking allows you to create cross-platform links.

The latest version **1.4.2.300** of [App Linking SDK](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-applinking-sdkchangenotes?ha_source=hms1) allows users to open links in iOS apps, and to set the information about an iOS app that enables App Linking.

---

The App Linking service of AGC is recommended.
By App Linking, if you have not installed the app, the AppGallery will prompt you to install the app first. After the installation is complete, you can view the specified content in the app.
For details, see the [official document](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-applinking-introduction?ha_source=hms1).

Comment: Actually i am aware of the AGC App Linking solution. However, there is a gap when a user try to send invitation from non-gms Huawei phone to Iphone or only gms android phones. Cross-platform deep link solutions what i need and apparently branch.io providing this solution but  just need to be sure.

Comment: 1) Currently, AppLinking does not support iOS, and it will support in Q3 2020.
2) Branch.io is an excellent solution, and it supports link redirection to AppGallery. 
https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/android-basic-integration

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a cross platform deferred deep linking platform like https://branch.io/ yet not sure if they support Huawei AppGallery at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

The App Linking function of our HMS phone already supports a similar function.